# How to add images in nested UIScrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, uiscrollview

I need to add images in scroll view multiple times. Am created a scrollview but images not append correctly in that.

My code is here :

```
-(void)sampleScroll
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50, (y + 95) * 5);

    // further configure
   [self.view addSubview: mainScrollView];
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image0.jpg",@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image3.jpg", nil];


    for(int i=0; i<[images count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",images);
        UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 250, 150)];
        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSString *img = [images objectAtIndex:i];
         NSLog(@"%@",img);
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"];
        NSLog(@"%@",imageView.image);
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1250,250);
        [scrollview addSubview:imageView];
        [mainScrollView addSubview:scrollview];
        y=y+155;
        //[self myscrollView];
    }
}
```

Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance..

Comment: i need to create image gallery..

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Use a UICollectionView instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame adjustment needed,

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;

UIScrollView * mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainScrollView.frame.size.width, mainScrollView.frame.size.height * COUNTS);
mainScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

for(int i = 0; i < COUNTS; i++)
{
   UIScrollView * scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, mainScrollView.frame.size.width - 20.0, mainScrollView.frame.size.height - 20.0)];
   scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
   scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
   scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,10.0, mainScrollView.frame.size.width - 40.0, mainScrollView.frame.size.height - 40.0)];
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"owl.jpg"];

   [scrollview addSubview:imageView];
   [mainScrollView addSubview:scrollview];

   y += mainScrollView.frame.size.height;
}

    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
```